Similar assumptions for log-rank and Cox model. Request for article reference
I understand that the Score function for a Cox model with a single binary predictor with a regression constant equal to zero equals the statistics for the log-rank test (a simple rewrite of the math). So, that is the main argument that log-rank test and the Cox model both assume proportional hazard.
See e.g. discussion at The logrank test statistic is equivalent to the score of a Cox regression. Is there an advantage of using a logrank test over a Cox regression?
However, I can not find any good reference to add to a paper within Oncology in which I need to justify using Cox and not log-rank. Actually, the problem is that the test of proportional hazard has a p-value below 5% (so in reality we can not use any of them). Some might argue that the log-rank test should be used since it "does not rely on any assumptions", which is the common understanding among non-statisticians. As stated above, I disagree with the use of the log-rank test (and the Cox). Still, I need a reference (which can also go into the paper we are working on) that I can use as part of my argumentation that the assumptions of the Cox and the log-rank actually are the same – not everyone sees the beauty in mathematical deviations. Can you provide any reference to a paper that can be useful related to the above problem? I can find plenty of online statements, but I need an article reference.

When you say "using Cox", what particular test are you referring to?

The log-rank test, & other common tests of the null Cox model, are valid even if the hazard functions for each value of the binary predictor are in truth non-parallel: under the null hypothesis the hazard functions are identical, not merely parallel. The issue, if there is one, is that they have low power to detect alternatives with e.g. crossing hazard functions.

Li et al. (2015), "Statistical Inference Methods for Two Crossing Survival Curves: A Comparison of Methods", PLOS One, 10, 1 & Lin et al. (2020), "Alternative Analysis Methods for Time to Event Endpoints under Non-proportional Hazards: A Comparative Analysis", Stat. Biopharm. Res., 12, 2 are perhaps the kind of studies you're after.

The argument isn't quite what you say. I'd recommend Chapters 7 and 8 of Klein and Moeschberger's Survival Analysis (second editiion, Springer, 2003) as a start.
A log-rank test doesn't assume proportional hazards (PH). The null hypothesis is that there is no difference in hazard over time among groups, up to the last time when all groups have an individual at risk (Equation 7.3.1 of Klein and Moeschberger). That said, the log-rank test has the highest power to find a difference in hazard over time between groups when PH holds.
It's also not the case that violation of PH makes a Cox model useless. What you get without PH is an event-averaged log-hazard ratio that can be used for inference with cluster robust standard errors. See this page and its links.
When PH doesn't hold (for example, with crossing survival curves), the log-rank test loses power and the event-averaged log-hazard ratio from a Cox model can be near 0. If there aren't tied event times, then the score test for the Cox model and the log-rank test will have identical loss of power, as you recognize.
Apparent PH violations ("a p-value below 5%") can sometimes just be the result of having a large number of events. Mis-specification of the functional form of a continuous covariate can also lead to PH violation. See this page for an introduction to those issues. Evaluate the magnitude and pattern of scaled Schoenfeld residuals over (an appropriate function of) time, and see whether the PH violation might be telling you something important.
